# Ruby/Python - Pynotify equivalent in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, python-2.7

My question is simple: is there a library in Ruby equivalent to Python's Pynotify?

Comment: It'd be useful for you to explain what Pynotify does, rather than expect people to chase down its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about how Pynotify allows you to easily implement the observer design pattern, the [`Observable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) module does this quite nicely for Ruby and is built in. There's a well documented example in the docs for how to implement a ticker which retrieves stock prices periodically.